# How To Upload an Image To My Flask Server With Flutter

Tags: flutter

**Since i'm new to flutter and i need to use a backend server to talk with it!***

**Html Version of upload working ! ==>**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="http://10.30.235.22:5000" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**Flutter Version of upload not working** ==>

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
 makePostRequest() async {

    Dio dio = new Dio();  
     FormData formData = new FormData.fromMap({
     "file": await MultipartFile.fromFile('asset/images/a.png',  filename: "a.png"),
  });
Response response = await dio.post("http://10.30.235.22:5000", data: formData);

  debugPrint(response.data);

  }
}
```

*Debug said he **does not recognize the path** that i give to him as" **asset/images/a.png**" but i see that the only package that has not much documentation. i didn't find another way to upload an image as form in flutter text**

Comment: Add the exact debug info formatted as code or quote in your post

Comment: did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add assets to the pubspec.yaml 
file. for details https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images

Comment: Yeah i did it before... and image.asset('asset/images/image.png') is working but when i include it in "file": await MultipartFile.fromFile('asset/images/a.png',  filename: "a.png"),.. error : Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot retrieve length of file, path =